# xsl:select elements who occur more times

Tags: xml, xslt

In the xsd file, I define a element has more occurrences:

```
<xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

so in the xml file the object may contain more "Type" elements.
In the xsl file, What I do is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Movies/Movie">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="Type"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

By this method, I can only get the first "Type" element in that node set. But I want to select all the "Type" elements existed in the "Movies/Movie" node set, is there a way to realize this?

Comment: This answer to a different question is interesting and might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6014992/422353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, when xsl:value-of selects more than one node, all but the first are ignored. In XSLT 2.0, you get the space-separated concatenation of all the selected nodes. It sounds from your evidence as if you are using XSLT 1.0. If you want to select multiple elements in XSLT 1.0, you need a for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Type">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, and I find that the XSLT 2.0 is much better, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use another `xsl:for-each` or use `xsl:apply-templates` instead.

Here's an example that doesn't use `xsl:for-each`...

**XML Input**

```
<Movies>
    <Movie>
        <Type>a</Type>
        <Type>b</Type>
        <Type>c</Type>
    </Movie>
    <Movie>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <Type>3</Type>
    </Movie>
</Movies>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Movie">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Type">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something as below(match and select with index as 1):

```
  <xsl:template match="/Movies/Movie">
       <xsl:value-of select="Type[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: @madth3: Oops, I misunderstood the question. Updated the answer.